# Regex to match [WORD]: [number] [number] [number]

Tags: java, regex

I'm pretty new to RegExs and I can never wrap my head around these things.
"WORD: 21.889236 21.889236 0" 
I'm trying to retrieve the WORD and the 3 numbers afterwards in full form, all decimals intact. This will also be ran through a file with multiple occurrences.
There will also be lines like this
"WORD: 1.0 1.0 0"

```
(\\w+):.([\\d[0-9].{8}).(\\d[0-9].{6})..(\\d[0-9])
```

This gives me an error inside eclipse.

Comment: Try testing in https://regex101.com/ .

Comment: There's more wrong than right with that regex. Perhaps you should start by reading a tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
\b(\w+):\s*(?:\d+(?:.\d+)?\s*){3}
```

In Java use:

```
"\b(\w+):\\s*(?:\\d+(?:.\\d+)?\\s*){3}"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yJ5bQ5/1)

Breakup:

```
\b          # word boundary
(\w+)       # match a word
:           # match literal :
\s*         # match 0 or more white-spaces
(?:         # start non-capturing group 1
   \d+      # match 1 or more digits
   (?:      # start non-capturing group 2
      .     # match a decimal point
      \d+   # match 1 or digits
   )?       # end non-capturing group 2 and make it optional
   \s*      # match 0 or more white-spaces
){3}        # end non-capturing group 2 and repeat it 3 times
```